# How to migrate to SpringBoot, Spring in action 4 Spitter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning from book Spring In Action 4. I have problem in chapter 5. I cant run this example with spring boot and maven. 
I get following mesage:
Consider defining a bean of type 'spittr.data.SpitterRepository' in your configuration.

I have this bean but componentScan doeasnt see it.

Here is whole code:
https://github.com/Kobooo/SpringInAction4Spitter

[Aplication files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvuOD.jpg)

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.howtodoinjava</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-demo</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-boot-demo Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tomcat Embed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- To compile JSP files -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Equals -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TESTS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.47</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

SpitterController.java

```
package spittr.web;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import spittr.Spitter;
import spittr.data.SpitterRepository;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spitter")
public class SpitterController {

    private SpitterRepository spitterRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SpitterController(SpitterRepository spitterRepository) {
        this.spitterRepository = spitterRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=GET)
    public String showRegistrationForm() {
        return "registerForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=POST)
    public String processRegistration(
            @Valid Spitter spitter,
            Errors errors) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "registerForm";
        }

        spitterRepository.save(spitter);
        return "redirect:/spitter/" + spitter.getUsername();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{username}", method=GET)
    public String showSpitterProfile(@PathVariable String username, Model model) {
        Spitter spitter = spitterRepository.findByUsername(username);
        model.addAttribute(spitter);
        return "profile";
    }

}
```

JdbcSpitterRepository.java

```
package spittr.data;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import spittr.Spitter;

@Repository
public class JdbcSpitterRepository implements SpitterRepository {

  private JdbcOperations jdbc;

  @Autowired
  public JdbcSpitterRepository(JdbcOperations jdbc) {
    this.jdbc = jdbc;
  }

  public Spitter save(Spitter spitter) {
    jdbc.update(
        "insert into Spitter (username, password, first_name, last_name, email)" +
        " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        spitter.getUsername(),
        spitter.getPassword(),
        spitter.getFirstName(),
        spitter.getLastName(),
        spitter.getEmail());
    return spitter; // TODO: Determine value for id
  }

  public Spitter findByUsername(String username) {
    return jdbc.queryForObject(
        "select id, username, null, first_name, last_name, email from Spitter where username=?", 
        new SpitterRowMapper(), 
        username);
  }

  private static class SpitterRowMapper implements RowMapper<Spitter> {
    public Spitter mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      return new Spitter(
          rs.getLong("id"),
          rs.getString("username"),
          null,
          rs.getString("first_name"),
          rs.getString("last_name"),
          rs.getString("email"));
    }
  }

}
```

SpringBootWebApplication.java

```
package spittr.web;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(new Class[] {SpringBootWebApplication.class} ,args);
    }
}
```

WebConfig.java

```
package spittr.web;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spittr.web")
@Import(spittr.config.DataConfig.class)
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }

}
```

DataConfig.java

```
package spittr.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;

@Configuration
public class DataConfig {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("schema.sql")
            .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }
}
```

SpitterWebInitializer

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import spittr.web.WebConfig;

@Configuration
public class SpitterWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
  }

}
```

root

```
package spittr.config;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.core.type.filter.RegexPatternTypeFilter;

import spittr.config.RootConfig.WebPackage;
import spittr.web.WebConfig;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"spittr"},
        excludeFilters={
                @Filter(type=FilterType.CUSTOM, value=WebPackage.class)
        })
public class RootConfig {
        public static class WebPackage extends RegexPatternTypeFilter {
                public WebPackage() {
                        super(Pattern.compile("spittr\\.web"));
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to add in the component scan the following package `spittr.data`, so it will scan and find your `@Repository`

Comment: Thanks, I added @ComponentScan({"spittr"}) to SpringBootWebApplication